# How to get the form data without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery

I have created the form below to ask what the visitor wants so I can indicate in a modal window how to get there. So I need to get the visitor's choices in the modal window without refreshing the page.

Here are my codes below.

```
<form id="wantedForm" method="POST">
    <div class="wanted-opt">
        <div class="wantoptiontitle">Je veux</div>
        <div class="wanted-options input-field">
            <select id="wanted-1" name="wanted-1">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wanted-opt">
        <div class="wantoptiontitle">comme ça je peux</div>
        <div class="wanted-options input-field">
            <select id="wanted-2" name="wanted-2">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-default btn modal-trigger" type="submit">Comment faire ?
    </button>
</form>
<div id="wantedModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
        <p><?php var_dump($_POST) ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Le script

```
$('#wantedForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wantedModal').modal('open');
});
```

When I do a `var_dump($_POST)` in the modal, it returns a null result. Can someone please tell me what I need to correct? Thank you for your help.

Please tell me what I need to change. Thank you.

EDIT

I had tried to do with ajax also with the code below. It hadn't worked either.

```
$('#wantedSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var wanted_1 = $('#wanted-1').val();
    var wanted_2 = $('#wanted-2').val();

    $.post(location.href, {wanted_1: wanted_1});
    $.post(location.href, {wanted_2: wanted_2});
    $('#wantedModal').modal('open');
});
```

Comment: Hi @Jay Thank you for your quick response. Yes, I thought I would need ajax, but I tried that too, without success.

Comment: use javascript to capture the users input and the populate into the modal

Comment: Do you need to persist your data in database before getting it in your modal?

Comment: No @FlorentRoques

Comment: I posted a solution below, tell me if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which gets your form data directly in your modal on submit:

```js
$('#wantedForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var wanted_1 = $('#wanted-1 option:selected').text();
    var wanted_2 = $('#wanted-2 option:selected').text();
    
    $('#choices')
    .empty()
    .append('<p>wanted 1: '+wanted_1+'</p>')
    .append('<p>wanted 2: '+wanted_2+'</p>');
    
    $('#wantedModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="wantedForm" method="POST">
  <div class="wanted-opt">
    <div class="wantoptiontitle">Je veux</div>
    <div class="wanted-options input-field">
      <select id="wanted-1" name="wanted-1">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wanted-opt">
    <div class="wantoptiontitle">comme ça je peux</div>
    <div class="wanted-options input-field">
      <select id="wanted-2" name="wanted-2">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn-default btn modal-trigger" type="submit">Comment faire ?
  </button>
</form>
<div id="wantedModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
    <div id="choices"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not posting the request by using `e.preventDefault();` that`s why $_POST is empty. You should collect submited values in JS like this.

```
var x = $('#wanted-1').val();
var y = $('#wanted-2').val();
```

and then you can open insert this values in modal elements like

```
$("#modal-element1").html(x);
```

Comment: Hi @Harut, Is there a way to save data with $_POST ?

Comment: @Worksfather the answer is No because the request is not reaching the PHP side of the code.